# php array variable

Tags: php, arrays

in my script,

```
$value= array("DK","Bloomsberry","McGrawHill","OXFORD","DC Books","Springer");

if(in_array("Bloomsberry",$value)){
echo "Bloomsberry is there inside the array";}
else{ echo "Bloomsberry is not there ";}
```

this works well

i have a variable `$names` which is a mysql result, which has data `"DK","Bloomsberry","McGrawHill","OXFORD","DC Books","Springer"` like an array data.

but when i place the variable inside like `$value= array($names);` instead of `$value= array("DK","Bloomsberry","McGrawHill","OXFORD","DC Books","Springer");` , i am getting result `"Bloomsberry is not there "` instead of expected `"Bloomsberry is there inside the array"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the " signs get escaped and that also the array is passed as an single string. You will have to split the string to an array. If I where you I would submit to mysql: "DK,Bloomsberry,McGrawHill"etc and then do

```
<?php
$string = "DK,Bloomsberry,McGrawHill,OXFORD,DC Books,Springer";
$array = explode(",", $string);
if(in_array("Bloomsberry",$array)){
  echo "Bloomsberry is there inside the array";}
else{ echo "Bloomsberry is not there ";}
```

The explode command returns an array split on the commas.
I hope this works for you

Answer (score 1):

If `$names` is already an Array, then `array($names)` is an Array containing one element (the one element is your `$names` array).

If you want to assign `$value` to the array `$names`, you simply use the assignment operator:

```
$value = $names;
```

Then do your conditional `in_array("Bloomsberry", $value);`. Or you could just avoid the assignment and do `in_array("Bloomsberry", $names)`.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the following difference:

```
$value = array("DK","Bloomsberry","McGrawHill","OXFORD","DC Books","Springer");
print_r($value);

/* produces:
Array
(
    [0] => DK
    [1] => Bloomsberry
    [2] => McGrawHill
    [3] => OXFORD
    [4] => DC Books
    [5] => Springer
)
*/
```

where as:

```
$value = array("DK","Bloomsberry","McGrawHill","OXFORD","DC Books","Springer");
$newValue = array($value);
print_r($newValue );

/* produces:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => DK
        [1] => Bloomsberry
        [2] => McGrawHill
        [3] => OXFORD
        [4] => DC Books
        [5] => Springer
    )
)
*/
```

`in_array("Bloomsberry", $newValue)` will only return true if "Bloomsberry" is a value in the first dimension of the array. However the only first dimension element in $newValue is the $value array.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:**

This is because `in_array` starts checking at the root node, and depending on how many levels the needle has depends in how many levels it checks within the haystack

An example of the above:

```
$a = array(array('p', 'h'), array('p', 'r'), 'o');

if (in_array(array('p', 'h'), $a))
{
    echo "'ph' was found\n";
}
```

`$a` is actually 2 levels of arrays, also called multi-dimensional.

Within your code your placing your root level array, into another array, thus the array of the DB Then becomes `array(array("results"))` this when you check the first node using `in_array("string")` it cant find it within the root haystack.

**Possible Fix:**

Just use the actual result as your in_array check, example:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    /*
        $row is  a single dimension and can be used like so:
    */
    if(in_array("Bloomsberry"),$row))
    {
        //Echo your success.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$name = '"DK","Bloomsberry","McGrawHill","OXFORD","DC Books","Springer"';
$name = str_replace('"', '', $name);
$value = explode(',', $name);
```

Now your below given code will work.

```
if(in_array("Bloomsberry",$value)){
echo "Bloomsberry is there inside the array";}
else{ echo "Bloomsberry is not there ";}
```